# Gorm NOT NULL constraints STILL PASSES FOR NULL values in the database Golang

Tags: postgresql, go, struct, go-gorm

In my struct, i have the following

```
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id         int       `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    UserId int       `json:"user_id" gorm:"Index;not null" validate:"required"`
    TaskId     int       `json:"task_id" gorm:"Index;not null" validate:"required"`
    JobId      int       `json:"job_id" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Latitude   float64   `json:"latitude" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Longitude  float64   `json:"longitude" gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    StartAt    time.Time `json:"start_at"`
    EndAt      time.Time `json:"end_at"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    UpdatedAt  time.Time
}
```

and i have this function that saves to the table with the following

```
{   "user_id": 1,
    "location":[5748.5445, 89790.454],
    "latitude": 89790.454,
    "longitude": 5748.5445,
    "startAt":  "2030-10-30T10:58:00.000Z",
    "endAt": "2031-10-30T10:58:00.000Z"
}

func CreateTask(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var opentask models.JobOpenTask
    
    if err := c.BodyParser(&opentask); err != nil {
        return c.Status(400).JSON(err.Error())
    }
    
    db.DB.Db.Create(&opentask)
    return c.Status(200).JSON("OK")
}
```

When this runs, it still saves the record on the DB but I expect it to throw and error when it tries to save since it is `not null` in my struct but why is it able to save to the Db without throwing an error?

Comment: Did you automigrate?

Comment: Yes i did @some-user

Comment: Just try removing gorm.Model in Task struct

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [sql.NullIntxx](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullInt16) or int/float pointer for this because default/empty values of int/float is 0, which is `not null` for database.

So gorm and DB will allow this to pass through as non null value.

Similarly for `string` type where one has to use `*string` or `sql.NullStting` as default value of `string` is "" (blank string) and not nil.

Answer (score 0):

- First you should check that migrations have been run properly that means `not null` constraint for `user_id, task_id, job_id, ..` columns are created in database.
- Secondly you have to use pointer because `golang` has a concept of `zero value` that means `int`, `float`, `string`, `bool` have default values of `0`, `0.0`, `""`, `false` accordingly, if you doesn't assign any value. But if you use pointer then this fields will be `nil` and eventually `NULL` will be sent in db. And if there is a `NOT NULL` constraint for that column error will occur.

Comment: Zero value playground [link](https://go.dev/tour/basics/12).

Answer (score 0):

- null just apply for pointer
- `gorm.Model` include

```golang
type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

you don't need declare `Id, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt` in your struct

- Correct your struct as bellow:

```golang
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId     int       `json:"user_id"`
    TaskId     int       `json:"task_id"`
    JobId      int       `json:"job_id"`
    Latitude   float64   `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude  float64   `json:"longitude"`
    StartAt    time.Time `json:"start_at"`
    EndAt      time.Time `json:"end_at"`
}
```

- And tag and best practice is control by database with column defined not null constraint
- `AUTO_INCREMENT`  should be create on the database when your create table , this need control by database , not by language
- declare table as bellow:

```sql
create table tasks (
   int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id int not null, 
   task_id int not null,
   job_id int not null,
   latitude int not null,
   longitude int not null,
   start_at datetime,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime
)
```

wish your study well!